# How to connect a function when the window quits?

Tags: c, gtk3

I have some memory on the heap that I have to free when the window quits. How can I use g_signal_connect to determine when the window quits? My question is very simple, so there is no need to type a lot.

Comment: As it stands it hard to determine what your problem is, you need to add a minimal complete example showing what you've tried.

Comment: @Jackson Come on. I made it VERY clear that I need to call free when the window is concluded

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Jackson Why?? I did not even do any thing wong and I asked a perfectly decent question

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of:

```
GtkWindow* window;
int* data_to_free = malloc(100);
g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (my_function), data_to_free);

void my_function(int* data) {
    free(data);
}
```

where my_function is the function you want to call when the window is closed with optional data_to_free (may be NULL if my_function accepts no args).

Comment: Hmm. I thought I tried that, but it would not hurt to trie again

Comment: Hmm. Intriguing. Only works when I click the ""x"" on the window

Comment: try replacing "destroy" with "delete"

Comment: `GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:46:36.560: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2523: signal 'delete' is invalid for instance '0x26c0280' of type 'GtkWindow'
`

Comment: are you connecting the signal to the main window or a different one

Comment: to the MAIN one

Comment: @hankSauri you say `destroy` *Only works when I click the x button*. How else do you close the window?

Comment: when you click on the x button it sends out the signal "delete-event" (the default handling for this is to destroy the window which sends out "destroy" signal)

Comment: @the other way I close the window is a button that calls exit(1) when clicked